# Issue instaling Dolphin @ Permissions Reversal scr

Tags: boonex-dolphin

am trying to install dolphin on my mac. I used the following to set up php and other required software.

http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan/

At permission reversal screen, I am asked to change the permission. Which i did so (chmod 400). However I received error. I reverted to writeable permission and tried again still I get the below error -

Warning: require_once(/Library/WebServer/Documents/~tusharsaurabh/pleasereferme/inc/version.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in/Users/tusharsaurabh/Sites/pleasereferme/inc/header.inc.php on line 154

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/Library/WebServer/Documents/~tusharsaurabh/pleasereferme/inc/version.inc.php' (include_path='.:') in/Users/tusharsaurabh/Sites/pleasereferme/inc/header.inc.php on line 154

When I check the file /Library/WebServer/Documents/~tusharsaurabh/pleasereferme/inc/version.inc.php, there is no tusharsaurabh folder under Documents folder. However /Users/tusharsaurabh/Sites/pleasereferme/inc/header.inc.php is present.

Please let me know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was $dir[root](in header.inc) had incorrect path. Corrected the path and installation was complete.